# Passing Extra data over Android AlertDialog single-choice list

Tags: android, list, hashmap, android-alertdialog

Here I've got the button listener which triggers the alertDialog.

```
btn_newKharcha.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        datasource.open();
        List<Partners> partners = datasource.findAll();

        Partners p = new Partners();
        String[] partners_arr = new String[partners.size()];

        for(int i=0; i<partners.size(); i++){
            p = partners.get(i);
            partners_arr[i] = p.getName();
        }

        alertSelectPartner(v, partners_arr);
    }
});
```

Doing this way, I can pass the names of the PARTNERS but not the PARTNERS_ID. And here's the alertDialog sample I created. While getting the integer which, I only can get the array indexing, which is not useful.

```
private void alertSelectPartner(View v, String[] partners_list) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Home.this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.select_partner);
    builder.setItems(partners_list, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    NewKharcha.class);
            intent.putExtra("partners_id", String.valueOf(which));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Is there any way like (Hashmaps) or something so that I can pass the partners_id with the Intent over OnClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.putExtra("partners_id", array);
```

Intents employ hasmaps under the hood. Access it by using `intent.getExtras().getIntArray()`

Comment: Thank you for the response. But it won't be partner specific. What I want is that, when user clicks the partner's name, the id related to that partner (not the alertdialog's string array index) should pass over the Intent.

Comment: Then you need to implement a function like `getPartnerId(int index)` which returns id of given index.

Comment: yup, now you came to the point. But the matter is, datasource.findAll(); gives me the partners name, id. which I later extracted it to a String[] array named partners_arr[]. Then passed that array into the alertDialog. But that way I can only get the names. Not the id's. Please give me some idea. to pass the id's

Comment: In your array there are only names. `partners_arr[i] = p.getName();` I don't know what your `datasource` does but it should give you partners ids too.

Comment: I can get the id by p.getId() but it's worthless until I can pass it by the onClickListener for alertdialog.

Comment: I can't help you more than this. You need to a function like `getPartnerId(int index)` as I said earlier.

Comment: You can implement your own Onclick listener which takes an integer as constructor parameter. By this way you can pass that partner id.